# How to convert grayscale png with transparency to heatmap?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, heatmap

The `heatmap` package isn't supported by Python 3, and `cv2` doesn't support the following for PNG images with an alpha channel:

```
cv2.applyColorMap(img, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

I want to convert a grayscale PNG image into a heatmap; in other words, colorize the darker pixels as blue and the brighter pixels as red.

Every pixel's transparency should remain unaffected.

Comment: Can you share an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try using matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap.

```
colormap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
heatmap = (colormap(image) * 2**16).astype(np.uint16)[:,:,:3]
heatmap = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

You can choose the color maps according to your desired output.